# Programs, VAOS, VBOS, multiple shaders

Tags: opengl

I am thinking of a scenario, in which, 
while pressing a button, a different shader is used for a certain object.

So, I was wondering about memory handling in the gpu.
I usually have been using glUseProgram before any glBufferData call,
as I usually have been associating an object with a program.

I am in need of more flexibility now. I was wondering, does glBufferData
fill a memory location in the GPU, which any program can access?
Or does glUseProgram have to be called 1st, for the memory to be allocated
for that certain program?

I don't want to be passing the same data twice, once for each program.
Is a VAO likewise associated with a certain program?
 

It seems to me that they should be irrelevant. Since glGetAttribLocation
takes the program ID as an argument, that should be enough to specify
an object's attributes in a specific program.
However, in that case, I'm not even sure why glUseProgram is used at all.

Comment: What does `glBufferData` have to do with shader programs?

Comment: Buffers do not have any direct association with shaders. Combining them is only done by the VAO (or better to say by the `glAttribPointer` calls). And even then, they are not bound to the program itself, but just to the attribute locations. As long as your shaders use the same locations, the same VAO can be used.

Answer (score 0):

Let's say you want to draw a car. You have a program (say, idP1 = 1) which uses VBO buffers buf1 and buf2 and attributes at1, at2. You store in a VAO (say, vao1) the needed bindings buf1 and buf2 to at1 and at2. Before you activate the drawing you active vao1 and "use" program idP1.

Now you want to draw a house. It has its own buffer buf3 and at1 attribute (yes, the same as for the car). You set a VAO (vao2) for the buf3 binding to at1. And it happens that the shader program is the same as for the car. No problem. You active vao2 and use idpP1. The shader will read at1 from buf3. at2 will not be used.

Now you want to draw a super-car. This needs a different shader. Buffers are the same as for a normal car, buf1, buf2, plus a new buf4. And they are readed in the shader the same way. Let's say by attributes at1, at2, at3. So you set a new VAO vao3, which sets bindings and attributes, perhaps for different locations in the shader. When you use this new program (idP2) it reads buf1 with at1, buf2 with at2 and buf4 with at3.

Notice that buffers are filled only once (or serveral, depending on how they change). You can create and fill a buffer when it's needed, not necessary at VAO creation. But VAO needs at least that the buffer is created before.